# Eclipse CDT indexer won't follow symlinks?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, symlink-traversal

In my source folders, I have two alternate versions of some part of my code, with a symlink choosing which one will be built. Now, in Eclipse, I use a resource filter to not see the two originals and only be able to see the symlink. However, for some reason, the indexer will not follow the link. I think I also got a message to the same effect.

Is there something I can do to make the indexer follow symlinks?

Comment: It works for me. Here's what I did to test: 1) Created two header files in my project, and a third one which is symlinked to one of the two. 2) Added resource filters to exclude the two original files. 3) Added an `#include` of the symlink to a `.cpp` file. 4) Clicked F3 on the `#include`. I was taken to a file whose named matched the symlink, and whose contents matched the correct target file. Testing with Eclipse Neon.2 on Debian 8.

Comment: Indexing was not working for me as I created a new project but not a C/C++ project. I deleted it. I created an "existing makefile project (C/C++)" in a new folder. Then created a new folder within Eclipse and *linked* the source code to it. Indexing is now working. I don't want to create the Eclipse project directly in the source code as it is managed by git and it will impact the .cproject files.